# Make a URL-encoded POST request using `http.NewRequest(...)`

Tags: http, go

I want to make a POST request to an API sending my data as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. Due to the fact that I need to manage the request headers, I'm using the [`http.NewRequest(method, urlStr string, body io.Reader)`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) method to create a request. For this POST request I append my data query to the URL and leave the body empty, something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    apiUrl := "https://api.com"
    resource := "/user/"
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("name", "foo")
    data.Add("surname", "bar")

    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(apiUrl)
    u.Path = resource
    u.RawQuery = data.Encode()
    urlStr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", u) // "https://api.com/user/?name=foo&surname=bar"

    client := &http.Client{}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlStr, nil)
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=\"XXXXXXX\"")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(data.Encode())))

    resp, _ := client.Do(r)
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

As I response, I get always a `400 BAD REQUEST`. I believe the problem relies on my request and the API does not understand which payload I am posting. I'm aware of methods like [`Request.ParseForm`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm), not really sure how to use it in this context though. Maybe am I missing some further Header, maybe is there a better way to send payload as a `application/json` type using the `body` parameter?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

URL-encoded payload must be provided on the `body` parameter of the `http.NewRequest(method, urlStr string, body io.Reader)` method, as a type that implements `io.Reader` interface.

Based on the sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    apiUrl := "https://api.com"
    resource := "/user/"
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("name", "foo")
    data.Set("surname", "bar")

    u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(apiUrl)
    u.Path = resource
    urlStr := u.String() // "https://api.com/user/"

    client := &http.Client{}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, urlStr, strings.NewReader(data.Encode())) // URL-encoded payload
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=\"XXXXXXX\"")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, _ := client.Do(r)
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

`resp.Status` is `200 OK` this way.

Comment: what if I dont want to send any data?? If I send any dummy data in place of ` bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode())`, will it work?

Comment: I'd try to send an empty *Buffer:

e.g. `b` given `var b bytes.Buffer`

Comment: var query = []byte(`query`) and then in your request:  req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(query))

Comment: You don't need to set the `Content-Lenght` header, as `http.NewRequest` does that already.

Comment: I think we can use `strings.NewReader(data.Encode())` (more efficient) instead of `bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode())`. At [func NewReader(s string) *Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader), it says "NewReader returns a new Reader reading from s. It is similar to bytes.NewBufferString but more efficient and read-only."

Comment: `data.Set` should be used for both `name` and `surname`, instead of `data.Add`. It sets value of the key, instead of appending another value to the same key, as `data.Add` does. `Add` works too, but does unnecessary `append(v[key], value)` to empty slice.