# How to send a POST request in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to make a POST request but I can't get it done. Nothing is received on the other side.

Is this how it is supposed to work? I'm aware of the [`PostForm`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm) function but I think I can't use it because it can't be tested with [`httputil`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil), right?

```
hc := http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", APIURL, nil)

form := url.Values{}
form.Add("ln", c.ln)
form.Add("ip", c.ip)
form.Add("ua", c.ua)
req.PostForm = form
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

glog.Info("form was %v", form)
resp, err := hc.Do(req)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253469/make-a-url-encoded-post-request-using-http-newrequest

Comment: what are you testing with `httputil`?

Comment: The http handler. I think it's a kind of e2e test

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You have mostly the right idea, it's just the sending of the form that is wrong. The form belongs in the body of the request.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
```

Comment: right... just now I was looking at that... it seems you need to read the source code not only the godoc to get how it's supposed to work.

Comment: don't forget to add the Content-Type before submitting: `req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Answer (score 71):

I know this is old but this answer came up in search results. For the next guy - the proposed and accepted answer works, however the code initially submitted in the question is lower-level than it needs to be. Nobody got time for that.

```
//one-line post request/response...
response, err := http.PostForm(APIURL, url.Values{
    "ln": {c.ln},
    "ip": {c.ip},
    "ua": {c.ua}})

//okay, moving on...
if err != nil {
  //handle postform error
}

defer response.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

if err != nil {
  //handle read response error
}

fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(body))
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-overview

Comment: You say OP's code was longer, than needed, but your code doesn't handle setting headers `req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is automatically set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by `PostForm`, according to: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#PostForm

Comment: If you want to add any other header to this, such as a basic authorization, is there a way?

Comment: @huggie No, the source documentation https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=28199:28281#L848 states: "To set other headers, use NewRequest and Client.Do."

Comment: Hrrmpf. I knew this was too easy — I hoped that there was a way to specify the headers using `http.PostForm`. Grumble, mumble...