# How to use two client.Do use golang

Tags: go, cookies, client

I use th go package net/http and i want to post to login url and then get the node page
I want to use twice client.Do because the cookies
Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := &http.Client{
        Jar: cookieJar,
    }

    loginUrl, _ := url.Parse("https://pro.v2bz.com/auth/login")

    v := url.Values{}
    v.Add("email", "1231231231@qq.com")
    v.Add("passwd", "1231231231")

    req := &http.Request{
        Method:   "POST",
        URL:      loginUrl,
        PostForm: v,
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("login failed", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    log.Println(resp.Status)

    nodeUrl, _ := url.Parse("https://pro.v2bz.com/user/node")
    nodeReq := &http.Request{
        Method: "GET",
        URL:    nodeUrl,
    }

    nodeResp, err := client.Do(nodeReq)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("node request failed", err)
    }
    log.Println(nodeResp.Status)
}
```

But i get this error 
**panic: assignment to entry in nil map**
How could i use twice client.Do in one code?

Comment: Don't just print errors and continue -- the `http.Response` can't be used if there was an error.

Comment: Also stop ignoring errors.  There are 3 places in that code where you're dumping an error return value into an underscore.  Check the errors, you can't just assume everything succeeds.  If it returns an error, it's because that function might fail.  And the panic stacktrace will specify exactly where in your code the failure happened.

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that you're creating an http.Request as a literal.  The Request struct has a map, Header, that you're not initializing.  Use http.NewRequest() instead.

Comment: It would be helpful to point out which line of the quoted code results in the quoted error.

Comment: Panic accor in the second **client.Do** .if i do not use the cookies i was ok but i could not keep the cokies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error occured in request.go (line 389):

```
// AddCookie adds a cookie to the request. Per RFC 6265 section 5.4,
// AddCookie does not attach more than one Cookie header field. That
// means all cookies, if any, are written into the same line,
// separated by semicolon.
func (r *Request) AddCookie(c *Cookie) {
    ...
    if c := r.Header.Get("Cookie"); c != "" {
        r.Header.Set("Cookie", c+"; "+s)
    } else {
        r.Header.Set("Cookie", s)
    }
}
```

See that request try to set Header. If you to make Header, will work.

```
nodeReq := &http.Request{
    Method: "GET",
    URL:    nodeUrl,
    TLS:    resp.TLS,
    Header: make(Header),
}
```

The appropriate method is http.NewRequest.
Link: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest

In http.NewRequest (request.go line 778), the Header is created like:

```
req := &Request{
    Method:     method,
    URL:        u,
    Proto:      "HTTP/1.1",
    ProtoMajor: 1,
    ProtoMinor: 1,
    Header:     make(Header),
    Body:       rc,
    Host:       u.Host,
}
```

See also that if you use HTTP, non-HTTPS, Header not is required and too will work!!

Comment: If i use https how to keep the cookies?

Comment: @YuanmengXiao, cookies in https works equals to http. An way is req.Header["cookie"]=[]string{"cookie data"}.

Comment: @YuanmengXiao, if the cookies are same as resp.Cookies then `nodeReq.AddCookie(resp.Cookies()[0])` (in your code)

Answer (score 3):

The error is not because you're using `client.Do` twice. In fact you can call it many times. Error message indicates that there is an unallocated variable (a `map`) being accessed somewhere. In your case, the variable which causing error is [`Request.Header`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request). Use appropriate method to construct request, e.g. [http.NewRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest):

```
nodeReq, err := http.NewRequest("GET", nodeUrl, nil)
```

When doing POST request for sending form content, use [Client.PostForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm), e.g.

```
resp, err := client.PostForm(loginUrl, v)
```

This method will set appropriate `Content-Type` header then call `client.Do`.

Comment: i want to define the request by myself but no to use the **http.NewRequest** or **client.PostForm**

Answer (score 0):

The panic accur because the **Request.Header** no initialize, at the second **Client.Do** the cookies could not add to **Request.Header** (NodeReq).
[In this link i learn how to add header by my self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493116/how-to-send-a-post-request-in-golang)
One solution is

```
v := url.Values{}
v.Add("email", "1231231231@qq.com")
v.Add("passwd", "1231231231")

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://pro.v2bz.com/auth/login", strings.NewReader(v.Encode()))
req.PostForm = v
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

At the second **Request** as @aristofanio-garcia say use

```
nodeReq := &http.Request{
    Method: "GET",
    URL:    nodeUrl,
    Header: make(http.Header), //add this to initialize Request.Header so the cookies could add into header
}
```