# How to generate deeply nested fields for api request using url.Values?

Tags: json, go

Using the url package https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#pkg-overview, one can create some data to send in an api request like so ([referencing this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493116/how-to-send-a-post-request-in-go)):

```
hc := http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", APIURL, nil)

form := url.Values{}
form.Add("ln", "value")
form.Add("ip", "value2")
form.Add("ua", "value3")
req.PostForm = form
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

glog.Info("form was %v", form)
resp, err := hc.Do(req)
```

My question is, how can one send nested json values?
Something like:

```
form.Add("ln", {"nestedKey": nestedvalue})
```

Is this possible? How can one send nested values?
More generally, how can one send a json body in a request?

Comment: You need to send a request body via the 3rd parameter of `http.NewRequest`.

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded does not have nested keys.  You can [marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) the value to a JSON []byte and add that value to the form: `form.Add("ln", string(jsonDoc))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

type m map[string]interface{}

func main() {
   form := m{
      "ip": "value2", "ua": "value3", "ln": m{"nestedKey": "nestedValue"},
   }
   b := new(bytes.Buffer)
   json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(form)
   http.Post("https://stackoverflow.com", "application/json", b)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Post