# How can I execute a GET request with a body in Go?

Tags: rest, http, curl, go

I am trying to write a client for an internal API endpoint that accepts a GET request with a JSON body:

`curl -X GET -d '{"foo":"bar"}' <my api>`

Since I can't change the API to accept a POST, I assumed implementing the same thing in Go would be trivial, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

I've tried to model my attempt after this example of a [URL encoded POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253469/make-a-url-encoded-post-request-using-http-newrequest) but not sure how I would alter this to work with a GET request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find some issue using the same technique you linked to and changing the method argument from `"POST"` to `"GET"`?

Comment: @Adrian Ya that was part of the issue, I thought  I could use 'url.Values{}' as the payload.

Comment: The payload should be the same as what works in `curl`.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working:

```
stmt := `{"foo": "bar"}`
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "<api>", bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(stmt)))

resp, _ := client.Do(r)
```

Comment: Rather than casting the `string` to a `[]byte` and wrapping that in a `bytes.Buffer`, you could just use [`strings.NewReader(stmt)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) which might be more straightforward.