# How to add URL query parameters to HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, go, httprequest

I am trying to add a query parameter to a HTTP GET request but somehow methods pointed out on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253469/make-a-url-encoded-post-request-using-http-newrequest)) don't work.

I have the following piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/callback", nil)
    req.URL.Query().Add("code", "0xdead 0xbeef")
    req.URL.Query().Set("code", "0xdead 0xbeef")
    // this doesn't help
    //req.URL.RawQuery = req.URL.Query().Encode()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("URL      %+v\n", req.URL)
    fmt.Printf("RawQuery %+v\n", req.URL.RawQuery)
    fmt.Printf("Query    %+v\n", req.URL.Query())
}
```

which prints:

```
URL      /callback
RawQuery 
Query    map[]
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/SYN4yNbCmo

Comment: Something wrong with `http.NewRequest("GET", "/callback?code=0xdead 0xbeef", nil)`?

Comment: @Adrian I didn't want to build the query myself - I have a bunch of variables that I need to attach there

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Check the docs for [`req.URL.Query()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query):

> Query parses RawQuery and returns the corresponding values.

Since it "parses RawQuery and returns" the values what you get is just a copy of the URL query values, not a "live reference", so modifying that copy does nothing to the original query.  In order to modify the original query you must assign to the original `RawQuery`.

```
q := req.URL.Query() // Get a copy of the query values.
q.Add("code", "0xdead 0xbeef") // Add a new value to the set.
req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode() // Encode and assign back to the original query.

// URL      /callback?code=0xdead+0xbeef
// RawQuery code=0xdead+0xbeef
// Query    map[code:[0xdead 0xbeef]]
```

Note that your original attempt to do so didn't work because it simply parses the query values, encodes them, and assigns them right back to the URL:

```
req.URL.RawQuery = req.URL.Query().Encode()
// This is basically a noop!
```

Comment: Well then I should hit myself in the head with "RTFM" sign. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very annoying API :(

Comment: Thanks for the docs quote because I couldn't figure out why the `RawQuery` overwrite was necessary just by reading StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly build the query params using `url.Values`

```
func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/callback", nil)
    req.URL.RawQuery = url.Values{
        "code": {"0xdead 0xbeef"},
    }.Encode()

    ...
}
```

Notice the extra braces because each key can have multiple values.