# 400 Bad Request when making a custom post request

Tags: http, go

I believe the problem lies in the url values. When I post this to the server, I will a 400 Bad Request: telling me that I need to have an email value. This leads me to believe that either the email value in editForm is getting parsed incorrectly, or the the first_value is, and then "tainting" the rest. I have seen this: [Make a URL-encoded POST request using `http.NewRequest(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253469/make-a-url-encoded-post-request-using-http-newrequest) and believe I am doing everything right, but this is throwing me off.

```
editForm := url.Values{}
editForm.Add("first_name", "supercool")
editForm.Add("email", "wow@example.com")
editForm.Add("username", "foo")

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, urlEndpoint, strings.NewReader(editForm.Encode()))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
client := http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I have double checked what the form data is supposed to be called, and I cannot see an error. For reference, this python code will work.

```
cn = {
    "first_name": "supercool",
    "email": "wow@example.com",
    "username": "foo"
}
r = requests.post(urlEndpoint, data = cn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending the content negotiation header.

### Content Type

> The Content-Type header field specifies the nature of the data in the 
>   body of an entity by giving media type and subtype identifiers, and by providing auxiliary information that may be required for certain 
>   media types.  After the media type and subtype names, the remainder of the header field is simply a set of parameters, specified in an attribute=value notation.  The ordering of parameters is not significant.

Here in this case the content is encoded in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so it has to be communicated to the server using `Content-Type` header

Please add the following before sending the request

```
 r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: @Peter yeah it does,  updated the answer after testing.thanks