# How Can I Submit Information To A Form using Go?

Tags: html, forms, go

I want to input `"foo"` for subject and `"bar"` for message and then submit the form. How do I do this using Go?

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a URL-encoded POST request using \`http.NewRequest(...)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253469/make-a-url-encoded-post-request-using-http-newrequest)

Answer (score 0):

When submitting information to a form, sometimes it's not enough to submit the form out of a method that returns a boolean”. For example, sometimes you have information that has to be submitted to multiple URLs, to save it to a database, etc… If you’re looking to submit information to a form, here are a few things you should know. First, when you create an HTML form and echo out the form elements using ‘htmlspecialchars’ and ‘htmlentities’, you sometimes have to double up the characters to submit it correctly. For example, if you echo out a form like this:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).