# Asana returning 400 error for go cde but works fine on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, go, asana

I have this nodeJS code which works fine

```
export const createAsanaAuthUrl = () => {
  // Store this in DB
  const codeChallenge = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(CODE_VERIFIER)
    .digest('base64')
    .replace(/=/g, '')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_');
  const udid = uuidv4();
  const url = `${ASANA_AUTH_BASE}/oauth_authorize?client_id=${ASANA_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${ASANA_REDIRECT_URL}&response_type=code&state=${udid}&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}`;
  return url;
};


export const getAsanToken = async (code: string) => {
  const params = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: ASANA_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: ASANA_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: ASANA_REDIRECT_URL,
    code,
    code_verifier: CODE_VERIFIER,
  };
  const { refresh_token, access_token } = (
    await axios.post(`${ASANA_AUTH_BASE}/oauth_token`, params, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    })
  ).data;
```

but the equivalent go code is throwing 400 error

```
func CreateAsanaAuthUrl(env *config.Env) string {
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(constants.AsanaCodeVerifier))
    codeChallenge := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hash[:])
    codeChallenge = strings.TrimRight(codeChallenge, "=")
    udid := uuid.New().String()
    url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/oauth_authorize?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&state=%s&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=%s", constants.AsanaAuthBase, env.AsanaClientId, env.AsanaRedirectUrl, udid, codeChallenge)
    return url
}

func GetAsanaToken (args domain.GetTokenArgs)  (*domain.ServiceAuthReturn, error) {
    env := args.Env
    params := TokenAsanaRequest{
    GrantType:    "authorization_code",
    ClientID:     env.AsanaClientId,
    ClientSecret: env.AsanaClientSecret,
    RedirectURI:  env.AsanaRedirectUrl,
    Code:         args.Code,
    CodeVerifier: constants.AsanaCodeVerifier,
    }
    fmt.Printf("p: %+v\n", params)
    url := constants.AsanaAuthBase + "/oauth_token"
    reqBody, err := json.Marshal(params)
    fmt.Printf("Url: %v", url)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(reqBody))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error", err) // log
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error sending Asana auth request: %s", err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode >= 400 {
    // server returned an error
        errorBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error:", err) // log
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error reading error response body: %s", err.Error())
        }
        log.Printf("Error response body: %s", string(errorBody)) // log error response body
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error getting asana auth token %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    var result struct {
        AccessToken string `json:"access_token"`
        RefreshToken string `json:"refresh_token"`
    }
```

It is throwing error here

```
        log.Printf("Error response body: %s", string(errorBody)) // log error response body
```

With status code being 400

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: In Node.js, you are trying to send the data using FormData but in Golang you are sending in JSON instead. Refer to this solution on StackOverflow to send the request in FormData format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19253970/8888888

Comment: @AngYC if I set data as `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` wouldn't it send as form data?